# Wordpress generate images size after upload

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I use this code for upload image :

```
function Generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
      $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else
      $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1 = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2 = set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

And this code for manual size :

```
if(function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('test', 260, 380, true);
}
```

If I upload from wordpress admin, `test` size make correct

But with my code, `test` size not make and show original size

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your last part.

1. You didn't add hook for the code. Without it, I doubt that the [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size) function will be executed. I suggest you wrap it in another function and add to `after_setup_theme` hook with `add_action` function.
2. I think the way you use `function_exists` is unnecessary. With the way you set that conditional block, it will always true because add_theme_support is a built-in core function.

Here is my suggestion code.

```
if( !function_exists('theme_setup') ) {
    function theme_setup() {
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
        add_image_size('test', 260, 380, true);
    }
    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup');
}
```

It's actually quite common way to interact your theme/plugin with WordPress core.

Comment: I replace your with my code. But not work and now, If upload from wordpress resize not work for me

Comment: Does your site a dev stage? Do you have debug plugins? [If no, install them](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/testing/#debug-bar). If yes, please show me the code. There must be a report, log or something can help us understand what's going on inside the code.